# Discord.py client.get_user returning None

Tags: python-3.x, discord, discord.py

I'm trying to make a bot where you can fight other people in your discord server, that allows you to @ mention a user to duel them. When I use the ID for client.get_user, though, it always returns None. I have turned on Precise Intent and Server Members Intent on the Discord Developer Portal and it still isn't working. Here is my test command I made:

```
import discord
import utils
from discord.ext import commands, tasks
from discord.ext.commands import Bot
from discord.utils import get
import random
import asyncio

intents = discord.Intents.default()
intents.members = True
client =  discord.Client(intents=intents)
client = commands.Bot(command_prefix = "e.")

@client.command()
async def duel(ctx, user_id):
    print(user_id)
    user = client.get_user(user_id)
    print(user)

client.run(No_lol)
```

When I type e.duel @user, it prints:
<@!ID> and None

Answer (score 0):

`user_id` is a string, but `get_user` is expecting an integer (the ID of a user).

```py
@client.command()
async def duel(ctx, user_id):
    print(user_id)
    user = client.get_user(int(user_id))
    print(user)
```

Though if you want to mention the user (not pass the ID manually) and convert it to a `discord.User` instance you should take a look at [converters](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/commands/commands.html#converters)

```py
@client.command()
async def duel(ctx, user: discord.User):
    ...
```